# How to check aes-ni are supported by CPU?

Tags: c, assembly, aes, aes-ni

I searching for solution, how to check **aes-ni** are available on CPU. I need to put this information in my application, so i'm not looking for any CPU-Z, bash commands or something.
I know that it is seen as **aes** flag. I have no idea how to check it in assembly or c. Main application is written in C#, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14077/how-to-check-that-aes-ni-is-supported-by-my-cpu . On linux `/proc/cpuinfo` is as available to C as it is to bash, but this requires of course a unix system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is returned by the `cpuid` instruction. Pass in `eax=1` and bit #25 in `ecx` will show support. See the intel instruction set reference for more details. Sample code:

```
mov eax, 1
cpuid
test ecx, 1<<25
jz no_aesni
```

Also, you might just try executing it and catch the exception.

Comment: Thank you, i made it that way.

Answer (score 2):

In visual C++

```
static bool GetNNICapability()
{
    unsigned int b;

    __asm
    {
        mov     eax, 1
        cpuid
        mov     b, ecx
    }

    return (b & (1 << 25)) != 0;
}
```